# Is there a way to fetch max and min values in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

Im using sphinx for document search. Each document has list of integer parameters, like "length", "publication date (unix)", popularity, ... .

The search process itself works fine. But is there a way to get a maximum and minimum fields values for a specified search query?

The main purpose is to generate a search form which will contain filter fields so user can select document`s length.

Or maybe there is another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if `length`, `date` etc are defined as attributes.

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#attributes

> Attributes are additional values
>   associated with each document that can
>   be used to perform additional
>   filtering and sorting during search.

Comment: You didnt get it. I know how to filter and select specified documents. The question was about aggregate functions without getting the documents. Btw, i already solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try GroupBy function by 'length' and select mix(length), max(lenght).

In SphinxQl it is like:

```
select mix(length), max(lenght) from index_123 group by length
```

The same for other attributes.